# Getting 403 Forbidden for the same request to server in second time

Tags: c#, multithreading, httpclient, http-status-code-403

I using HttpClient object make an http call to retrieve audio content of file. Somehow same request works for first time but when i seek the content and make the new request with same set of headers i am getting 403 Forbidden error.

I just don't understand what exactly causing the error. I tried to set User-agent in DefaultRequestHeaders but nothing is working.

```
await httpClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, token).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Response Header 
ContentType = application/vnd.apple.mpegurl
Set-Cookie =  some value

Please suggest me what could be wrong

Comment: Maybe a CSRF token. Just a guess.

Comment: Should i add any random CSRF to each request or server should send one which i have to use subsequently?

Comment: Can you post the rest of the request code? Namely the headers

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the HTTP client headers. I faced the same problem, then cleared the HTTP client headers and it worked.

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
```

before sending the request should solve the problem.